# Implement .gitignore behavior in a shell script?

Tags: macos, git, bash, shell

I'm writing a shell script that syncs files and I want to give users the ability to exclude certain files from syncing by creating a `.syncignore` file similar to Git's `.gitignore` file. According to the [gitignore documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), and my own experiments, these exclusion rules are more complicated than a simple glob match. Some examples:

1. If you have `foo` in your `.gitignore` file, it will exclude `foo` appearing *anywhere* in the path (e.g. `./foo`, `./bar/foo`, and `./bar/foo/baz` would be excluded) but not partial matches of `foo` (e.g. `./foobar`, `./bar/foobar/baz` would NOT be excluded).
2. If you include a slash, then the rule is applied relative to the current directory. For example, if you have `/foo` in your `.gitignore` file, it will exclude `./foo` but not `./bar/foo`.
3. You can include wildcards. For example, `foo*` will exclude `./foo`, `./foobar`, and `./bar/foobar/baz`.

Is there any easy way to replicate the exclusion rules for `.gitignore` in a shell script on OS X?

Comment: Do you have a reason to want to copy their exclusion rule system? It is complicated and somewhat confusing? Would a simpler matching/etc. implementation not be easier on you and your users? (Unless this is a tool designed *specifically* to work with git that is.)

Comment: @EtanReisner: That's a fair question. I guess I wanted to keep it consistent since people are used to `.gitignore` and its approach has been copied by other systems (e.g. `.dockerignore` for Docker). In other words, it's the only "standard" I know for exclusion rules. That said, I'm open to other ideas if they are vastly simpler/cheaper to implement, but still powerful.

Comment: The documentation for `.dockerignore` says nothing about using git-style matching. It says it uses "Go's filepath.Match" rules.

Comment: @EtanReisner: well I'll be damned, I could've sworn I read it behaved just like `.gitignore`, but I have no idea why. Well, are you aware of any other "standard" ways to do exclusion rules? Just shell globs?

Comment: Regular expressions and shell-like/`fnmatch`-style globs are the two general styles of matching I know of (short of fuzzy matching but you absolutely do not want that here). Both of which you can use in a shell script fairly easily. That being said just using something like `rsync` may be a simpler and more robust answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `rsync` to synchronize the files. Use its existing include/exclude pattern support. Put the rules in `.rsync-filter` and pass the `-F` flag to make it read the patterns from that file.

   [rsync man page](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html)
2. Just use `git`. Make sure you have git 2.3.0 or later on both sides, and use [push-to-deploy](https://github.com/blog/1957-git-2-3-has-been-released).

Comment: Thanks. I went with the option of allowing `rsync` to handle the exclusion rules. To avoid `rsync` spamming `stdout` with useless info for excluded files, I removed the `--verbose` flag and instead added a custom log format: `--log-format 'Syncing %n'` (`%n` is the filename being synced).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Yes, it's a solution to their ultimate problem, but not the question itself.

Comment: You’re right. The actual question is “Is there any easy way to replicate the exclusion rules for .gitignore in a shell script on OS X?” The answer is no, there is no easy way.